# set On Click Listener feature, an error occurs

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a problem and I hope anyone can help me
When I give the button id and go to Main Activity to use the button with the set On Click Listener feature, an error occurs
Kotlin language

Comment: can you specify  "an error occurs"

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking first; eg. it would help when you'd not only complain but provide an actual **error message**; when it reads `NullPointerException`, my guess was right.